# Not able merge guest cart with logged in user cart from programatically login

Tags: magento2, php, login, shopping-cart

I have create new login step in magento 2 checkout. When i add product to cart ,goto checkout and login from step guest user cart not merge with logged in user cart. Below is the code for login.

```
$customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate(
                $credentials['username'],
                $credentials['password']
            );
            $this->customerSession->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
            $this->customerSession->regenerateId();
            $redirectRoute = $this->getAccountRedirect()->getRedirectCookie();
            if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $redirectRoute) {
                $response['redirectUrl'] = $this->_redirect->success($redirectRoute);
                $this->getAccountRedirect()->clearRedirectCookie();
            }
```